# Python - Send Email From Shared Mailbox without using "On Behalf Of"

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

I am trying to send an email from "Shared Mailbox" Without using "On Behalf of".

I am able to go into that Mailbox from Outlook and send emails manually and when I do that, It doesn't put the "On Behalf of" Tagline.

But I am not able to do the same with a Programming Language.

So far, I have tried these and learned the following lessons.

```
import win32com.client as win32

def send_email(sender,recipient):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = "Test Emails"
    mail.HTMLBody = "Test Content"
    mail.SendUsingAccount = sender
    mail.Send()

recipient = "abc@company.com"
sender= "Mailbox@company.com"

send_email(sender,recipient)
```

This piece of code, doesn't send it from Mailbox@company.com

But rather sends it from my personal outlook account.

So then I went on to find, If I can see every account that I have, it doesn't show up the Mailbox account there.

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
for acc in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    print (acc)
```

But I sure do have access. I am seeing it on my outlook. I am able to send emails manually by selecting the account that I want to send it from using Outlook.

What am I missing here. Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to, go back to the admin team and ask them to disable "on behalf of" from the mailbox settings and then start using Sentonbehalfof in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. So, you need to get the right account object and then assign it to the property. It doesn't accept string values.

Here is a VBA sample:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount()  
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account  
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts  
 If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then  
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem  
 Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account"  
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com")  
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll  
 Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount  
     oMail.Send  
 End If  
 Next  
End Sub
```

Or Python:

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
oacctouse = None
for oacc in o.Session.Accounts:
    if oacc.SmtpAddress == "sender@mail.com":
        oacctouse = oacc
        break
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
if oacctouse:
    Msg._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, oacctouse))  # Msg.SendUsingAccount = oacctouse

if to:
    Msg.To = ";".join(to)
if cc:
    Msg.CC = ";".join(cc)
if bcc:
    Msg.BCC = ";".join(bcc)

Msg.HTMLBody = ""

Msg.Send()
```

Comment: Tried the python code, it still sends it from my personal account and not from the shared mailbox.

Comment: It's not working as I am not seeing my mailbox in o.Session.Accounts.

Comment: It seems the account is not configured in your profile. If so, you may try to use the [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property instead.